# How to add more nodes to the ring in Consistent Hashing for Databases

Tags: architecture

This question is an extension of the technique i.e., Consistent Hashing with regards to Database servers as nodes on the ring.

In consistent hashing, there are several servers that are distributed on the ring. What are my options if my server(s) start reaching their limit in terms of storage or become a hotspot frequently? How can I add more server(s) to the ring?

Comment: did you find a soluition for your facing problem? how to rehashing the legacy keys? @py_ios_dev

Answer (score 1):

When you add a new server to the ring, you need to take H / N keys from the other servers (combined), and assign them on the new server, where H is the total number of keys and N is the total number of servers. This should be done as part of the scaling process.

In order to avoid hotspots, you may need to replicate the data and load-balance the traffic on the same key (the hotspot key) between the replicas.

Comment: In the real world, the data consistently changes. How can we implement that as we identify those H/N keys and store the data corresponding to those on the new server?

Comment: This is implemented in Cassandra as far as I know, maybe checking the design docs of the consistent hashing algorithm would help, if you need specific details. It is a broad subject, though.